# Select Spreadsheet From Dropdown To Query In Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a pretty extensive spreadsheet that stores data over many years, and to help culminate that data I have a had to make multiple summary pages to calculate the data one for each year. I want to instead make a single sheet that will summarize the data and the user can simple select the year they want to view from a drop down menu and all the formulas will automatically calculate the new data. From what I can tell this can be done by using the "indirect" function but I cannot get it to work and am starting to think that function will not work because of the way the formula works. Does anyone have a working method that will generate the desired results.

Manual Formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369)>=1)*(MONTH('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369)<=3)*('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369<=TODAY())*(ISNUMBER(FIND("Work",'W.A.R. 2016'!B4:B369))+(ISNUMBER(FIND("Wrk/Lve",'W.A.R. 2016'!B4:B369))/2)))
```

Formula im working on.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(INDIRECT("'("&O2&")'!$A4:$A369"))>=1)*(MONTH(INDIRECT("'("&O2&")'!$A4:$A369"))<=3)*(INDIRECT("'("&O2&")'!$A4:$A369")<=TODAY())*(ISNUMBER(FIND("Work",INDIRECT("'("&O2&")'!$A4:$A369")))+(ISNUMBER(FIND("Wrk/Lve",INDIRECT("'("&O2&")'!$A4:$A369")))/2)))
```

In theory I cannot see why its not working but I think it the way indirect pulls the data.

Comment: Please could you add a screenshot showing what your data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I can spot a couple of issues.

1. This has unnecessary brackets around the sheet name:

   INDIRECT("'("&O2&")'!$A4:$A369")

It will produce a string like:    '(W.A.R. 2016)'!$A4:$A369

You just want to use:

```
INDIRECT("'" & O2 & "'!$A4:$A369")
```

2. There is some inconsistency in your formulas

The first formula searches for "Work" in B4:B369 and "Wrk/Lve" in B4:B369, whereas the second formula has the ranges swapped around.

The best advice I can give on trying to figure out where a formula is going wrong is using the Evaluate Formula tool.

Select the cell that has the formula, go to the Data tab on the ribbon and click Evaluate Formula. It will pop up a dialog that allow you to step through each part of the formula as it calculates. From there you should be able to see what's going wrong.